# CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', @PasswordWithSalt ),2) equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, hashbytes

I'm trying to move authentication from the stored procedure to EF. The SQL  itself is returning 2 results. How should I validate them?

The value is to be checked against the value stored in the table

```
ECC2065575DCBF977CD923996C598C3DC481404E
```

SQL syntax:

```
Declare @Password AS NVARCHAR(256) = 'Quest_2016'

DECLARE @PasswordSalt AS NVARCHAR(5) = 'LCY''n'

DECLARE @PasswordWithSalt AS NVARCHAR(261) = @Password + @PasswordSalt

print @PasswordWithSalt
```

result:`1 Quest_2016LCY'n`

```
print HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', @PasswordWithSalt )
```

result 2: `0xECC2065575DCBF977CD923996C598C3DC481404E-----`

```
print HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', 'Quest_2016LCY''n')
```

result 3: `0x5E85AB2ED11CDB696BC0544131D7C8571F4F8FA8-----`

Also just what how this can be implemented in C#

[sql hashbytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ZYa.png)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with those two queries is that the string values are the same but the bytes are not.

The first query

> print HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', @PasswordWithSalt )

uses unicode encoding to get the bytes so every character is 2 bytes (0x510075006500730074005F0032003000310036004C004300590027006E00).

The second query

> print HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', 'Quest_2016LCY''n')

uses ASCII so that every character is one byte.

To have the same result in the second example prefix the String with `N'`. It will tell SQL server that this is a unicode string

> print HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', N'Quest_2016LCY''n')

produces the hash `0xECC2065575DCBF977CD923996C598C3DC481404E`

In C# you can also use SHA1 to get the hash of the string and here also you need to be specific about the byte encoding

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(@"Quest_2016LCY'n");
byte[] hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(data);
Console.Write(hash.Select(x=>x.ToString("X2")).Aggregate((x,y)=>x+y));
```

prints `ECC2065575DCBF977CD923996C598C3DC481404E` but if you change `Encoding.Unicode` to `Encoding.ASCII` it gives the `5E85AB2ED11CDB696BC0544131D7C8571F4F8FA8`.